How to add an app icon when packaging my Electron app using Electron Forge?
While trying to add a custom app icon to my packaged Electron app I followed these steps: "https://www.electronforge.io/guides/create-and-add-icons#windows-and-macos" but apparently it didn't work out for me. All my main files are in "Electron/" and my icons (proxyClicker.ico, proxyClicker.icns and proxyClicker.png) are inside "Electron/assets/icons/". the commands "npm run make" and "npm start" work as they should (no errors), but my app icon for the packaged .exe inside of the "out" folder (where the packaged app and its files are being generated) is still displaying the default Electron icon. (I also tried switching directories and deleting the "out" folder before repackaging bc of windows icon caching) Does anyone know how to add a custom app icon to the packaged Electron app? (I am on Windows 11 and using Electron Forge for packaging btw.). My forge.config.json looks like this:
const { FusesPlugin } = require('@electron-forge/plugin-fuses');
const { FuseV1Options, FuseVersion } = require('@electron/fuses');

module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
    icon: '/assets/icons/proxyClicker'
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
      config: {},
    },
    // Fuses are used to enable/disable various Electron functionality
    // at package time, before code signing the application
    new FusesPlugin({
      version: FuseVersion.V1,
      [FuseV1Options.RunAsNode]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableCookieEncryption]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeOptionsEnvironmentVariable]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeCliInspectArguments]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableEmbeddedAsarIntegrityValidation]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.OnlyLoadAppFromAsar]: true,
    }),
  ],
};

and my package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "electron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Voltiq",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "Calculator",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron/fuses": "^1.8.0",
    "electron": "^30.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.1"
  }
}

A I said I mainly followed these steps to display my app icon after packaging: https://www.electronforge.io/guides/create-and-add-icons
There is also an old stackoverflow question regarding a similar case, but it also didn't help me: How to set app icon for Electron / Atom Shell App
(Yes, I also asked chatGPT)

Please try to remove the leading /, i.e. let the path of the icon start with assets/ and not /assets/. If that works, please read up on how paths work.

Thanks Alex. I already tried that and got an error and thought that this also wouldn't get me anywhere but after giving it a second try after reading your comment and actually being able to fix that new error (corrupted .ico file), it has worked :)
